# Passing model to custom angular directive for validation

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I've created a small angularjs directive for displaing validation error on my page

Here is code

```
.directive('validationErrors', function() {
        return {
            templateUrl: '/Content/biz/templates/common/validation-errors.html',
            replace: true,
            restrict: 'E',
            scope: {
                modelToValidate: '=',
                modelMinLength: '=',
                modelMaxLength: '=',
                modelPattern: '='
            }
        }
    });
```

And template for it

```
<div class="col-sm-5 pull-right" data-ng-show="modelToValidate.$dirty && modelToValidate.$invalid">
<span class="label label-warning" data-ng-show="modelToValidate.$error.required">This field is required!</span>
<span class="label label-warning" data-ng-show="modelToValidate.$error.minlength">Minimum field length should be  {{modelMinLength}}</span>
<span class="label label-warning" data-ng-show="modelToValidate.$error.maxlength">Maximum field length should be  {{modelMaxLength}}</span>
<span class="label label-warning" data-ng-show="modelToValidate.$error.pattern">Model should have {{modelPattern}}</span>
```

Than I bind it to a model

```
 <div class="col-sm-4">
                            <input class="form-control" ng-model="data.Main.FullName" ng-maxlength="1000" required/>
```

This generates markup like so

```
<div class="col-sm-4">
                            <input class="form-control ng-valid-maxlength ng-dirty ng-valid-parse ng-invalid ng-invalid-required ng-touched" ng-model="data.Main.FullName" ng-maxlength="1000" required="">
                            <div class="col-sm-5 pull-right ng-isolate-scope" model-to-validate="data.Main.FullName" model-max-length="1000">
<span class="label label-warning ng-hide" data-ng-show="modelToValidate.$error.required">This field is required!</span>
<span class="label label-warning ng-binding ng-hide" data-ng-show="modelToValidate.$error.minlength">Minimum field length should be </span>
<span class="label label-warning ng-binding ng-hide" data-ng-show="modelToValidate.$error.maxlength">Maximum field length should be 1000</span>
<span class="label label-warning ng-binding ng-hide" data-ng-show="modelToValidate.$error.pattern">Model should have </span>
```

But If binded model has error nothing is showen. Please help me to understand why is it so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you need to pass to you form is a a `ngModelController` instance, whereas what you are passing is a model instance.

Firstly change the input to have a name attribute

`<input name="fullName" class="form-control" ng-model="data.Main.FullName" ng-maxlength="1000" required/>`

(Also make sure your form has a name attribute, let's assume it is `myForm`)

And then the directive parameter should be

`<div model-to-validate="myForm.FullName" model-max-length="1000">`

This should now work. Remember all the properties that you are using like `$error` are defined on the NgModelController instance not on the model.

Also what you are doing can be done in Angular 1.4 using [ngMessage](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngMessages/directive/ngMessages)